# mysql trouble referencing parameterized select column in derived table

Tags: mysql

Is this working as designed?  mysql is not giving me visibility in to a parmeterized column from a derived table.  In the following example, I'd expect both column1Value and column2Value returned, but it's not returning column2Value, the parameterized value.

```
mysql> select version();
+--------------------+
| version()          |
+--------------------+
| 5.1.56-rel12.7-log |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'select a.* from (select "column1value" as column1, ? as column2) a';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> SET @a = 'column2Value';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a;
+--------------+
| column1      |
+--------------+
| column1value |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I have exhausted myself trying to solve this. I can't get it to work in MySQL either. Favorited though, because I would like to see if this gets resolved.

Comment: Given the lack of response here, I'm assuming it's a mysql bug.  I've reported it with bug 74621.  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74621

Comment: It looks like whoever commented also had the same issue. Any confirmation of whether or not this was a bug?

Comment: Yes... this was verified as a bug.  See here for more details:  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74621